# How can I ensure repeatability while parallelizing a randomly seeded experiment?

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, random, multiprocessing

I'm using [Mydia](https://mrinaljain17.github.io/mydia/videos.html#mydia-videos) to extract random frames from videos. Because I have a lot of videos, I want to parallelize this workflow while maintaining repeatability. `mydia.Videos` accepts a random seed, which is important for ensuring repeatability. Now I need to work on the parallelization piece.

Given `n` videos and a random seed, `r`, how can I ensure that the extracted frames for each video is the same regardless of the number of workers? I'm particularly interested in the algorithmic component, not necessarily the code.

My initial thought was to use `multiprocessing.Pool`. However, there will be a race condition in sampling the frames if the processes' completion times are non-determinstic; i.e., if proc 1 takes longer than proc 0, the sampled frames from the `Videos` class will be different than if proc 0 takes longer than proc 1.

Comment: Intuitively: hack that lib to not use `np.random.seed(random_state) + np.random.rand()` but `r = np.random.RandomState(17) + r.rand()`. Meaning: one PRNG for every worker. Not sure why this is not done more often. PRNG pollution seems to be a thing (i think Jupyter/ipython did that in it's gui in the past).

Comment: @sascha to be sure, child processes will maintain the `np.random.RandomState` -- how does this ensure that out-of-order processing still samples in the same order? Sorry if this is obvious, but I'm having trouble intuiting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution is a bit unorthodox because it's library-specific. Mydia allows to pass the frames to extract in lieu of forcing the `Videos` client to sample directly. This affords me the opportunity to  precalculate the frames to sample in the parent process. By doing this, I can "mock" the randomness in the subprocesses by instantiating a new `Videos` with those frames. For instance:

```
class MySampler:
   def __init__(self, input_directory: Path, total_frames: int, num_frames: int, fps: int):
       self.input_directory = Path(input_directory)

       self.frames_per_video = [
            self.__get_frame_numbers_for_each_video(total_frames, num_frames, fps)
            for _ in self.input_directory.glob("*.mp4")
        ]

    @staticmethod
    def get_reader(num_frames: int, frames: List[int]):
        # ignores the inputs and returns samples the frames that its constructed with
        return Videos(target_size=(512, 512), num_frames=num_frames, mode=lambda *_: frames)
```

and then I can simply parallelize this:

```
   def sample_frames(self, number_of_workers: int):
        pool = Pool(processes=number_of_workers)    
        videos = list(self.input_directory.glob("*.mp4"))

        pool.starmap_async(self.read_video, zip(self.frames_per_video, videos))    

        pool.close()
        pool.join()
```

where `read_video` is the method that calls `get_reader` and does the reading.